# nosetests won't run in venv on windows 10

Tags: python, powershell

I've run into a brick wall! I've followed various suggestions on stackoverflow.
I am running Python2.7 on windows, with `Environment Variables>system path` set to `C:\Python27\Scripts`. I have downloaded 'Virtual Environment'.
I have Administrator: Windows PowerShell running `venv`. After all this I still cannot run 'nosetests'. It just repeats that `nosetests: The term 'nosetests' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, etc. etc.` 
What do I have to do to get this thing to run??

Having been downgraded to '-1', could you please tell me if its not well researched, or if its unclear, or irrelevant? That would be helpful for future questions.

Comment: Are you trying to run `nosetests` in a virtualenv python environment?  Because even if nose is installed to your system python, it won't automatically be installed to your virtual environments

Comment: Okay, having established `C:\Python27\venv`, I have also copied all `nose2` files into `\venv\Scripts`. I tried `nosetests` again - still the same error.

Comment: Still didn't answer my question

Comment: Yes I am - with PowerShell in Administrator mode.

Comment: and you are using the PoSh console but not Python's precisely why?

Comment: As a command-line interface?

Comment: FYI: My 'weapon of choice' is Ubuntu, not Windows. I'm trying to create an .exe from a python script. I'm finding Windows ridiculously more difficult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't create your virtual environment in the Python program directory. And don't copy the nosetests files to the `venv` directory. Use `pip` to install the relevant package(s).

The description from [The Hitchhiker's Guide to Python](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) seems to work for me:

```
PS C:\Temp> New-Item -Type Directory test >$null
PS C:\Temp> Set-Location .\test
PS C:\Temp\test> C:\Python27\Scripts\virtualenv.exe -p C:\Python27\python.exe venv
Running virtualenv with interpreter C:\Python27\python.exe
New python executable in C:\Temp\test\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
PS C:\Temp\test> . .\venv\Scripts\activate.ps1
(venv) PS C:\Temp\test> pip install nose
Collecting nose
  Downloading nose-1.3.7-py2-none-any.whl (154kB)
    100% |################################| 163kB 1.1MB/s
Installing collected packages: nose
Successfully installed nose-1.3.7
(venv) PS C:\Temp\test> nosetests -V
nosetests version 1.3.7
```

Tested on Windows 7 with PowerShell 4, but I don't expect Python to behave any different on Windows 10.

Comment: I have downloaded according to that description. Successfully installed but with warning!  `c:\python27\lib\distutils\__init__.py:14: UserWarning: The virtualenv distutils package at %s appears to be in the same location as the system distutils?` Have deleted previous instances of venv, but something must still be screwing up the works.

Comment: Please re-read the very first sentence of my answer: **Don't create your virtual environment in the Python program directory.**

Comment: Understood. I've decided to start with a clean slate - resetting Windows.